# Scheduling Windows job to run a PHP script failing

Tags: php, windows, drupal, scheduled-tasks

I have a PHP script which exports data from SQL table into Drupal content. I would like to schedule the job as a windows task and followed the below steps:

1. My PHP file contains below code:

```html
 <?php
     namespace Drupal\Import\Commands; 
     use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;
     use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
    
    class ImportCommands extends DrushCommands 
    {
        public function loadData() 
     {
            $tx = \Drupal::database()->startTransaction();
            try 
      {
                $query_result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                                    ->condition('type', 'test_mod')
                                    ->execute();
                entity_delete_multiple('node', $query_result);
       
                $database = \Drupal::database();
                $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM my_sql_table");
                $records = $result->fetchAll();
       
          
                foreach($records as $key => $record) {
                    $node = Node::create(['type' => 'test_mod']);
                    $node->set('title', $key);
        $node->set('field_IDVal', $record->ID);
        $node->set('field_name', $record->Name);
                    $node->status = 1;
                    $node->enforceIsNew();
                    $node->save();
                }
       
            } 
      catch (Exception $e) {
                $tx->rollBack();
                // log/report failure
            }
    
            // $tx->commit();
        }
    
    }
```

2. Created .bat file and have the below query:

call C:\MyProj\web\Commands\php.exe -f C:\MyProj\web\Commands\ExportCommands.php

3. Created a windows task to link with this file.

All I am seeing is 0x1 with the task success. Any help to make this work?!

Expected behavior: I want to create a wndows task that calls this PHP fine and the command in the file loads data from SQL table to Drupal.

Right now I execute the file by going to commandprompt and do: drush MyProj:loaddata

Any help?!

Comment: Your `php.exe` file is located at `C:\MyProj\web\Commands\php.exe`?

Comment: I moved it to my project folder to stay along with my PHP file. Originally it belongs to Program Files

Comment: The `call` command is for batch files, so that when a nested batch file finishes, the one it was contained in resumes. Possibly your use of `call` on executable (php.exe) is the problem. Or is whats masking the results. .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call

Answer (score 0):

Php.exe is in wrong place. Move it to it's original location